# Use select in Semantic UI with Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, formik, semantic-ui-react

I'm usign [Formik](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik) to validate some data fields with [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html) in React. It works fine with input fields but doesn't work with selectors.

How it works with input fields:

```
    import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
    import { Input, Button, Select, Label, Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react';
    import * as Yup from 'yup';

    ...

  const initialValues = {
     name: ''
  };
  const requiredErrorMessage = 'This field is required';
  const validationSchema = Yup.object({ name: Yup.string().required(requiredErrorMessage) });
   
  <Formik
  htmlFor="amazing"
  initialValues={initialValues}
  validationSchema={validationSchema}
  onSubmit={values => this.handleSubmit(values)}>
  {({ errors, touched }) => (
    <Form id="amazing">
      <div>
        <CreationContentContainer>
          <Grid>
            <Grid.Column>
              <Label>Company name</Label>
              <Field name="name" as={Input} placeholder="name" /> // here is the input 
              <div>{touched.name && errors.name ? errors.name : null}</div>
            </Grid.Column>
          </Grid>
        </CreationContentContainer>
        <Button type="submit" form="amazing">
          Create company
        </Button>
      </div>
    </Form>
  )}
</Formik>;
```

However, when the `as={Input}` is replaced by `as={Select}`, it doesn't work. The dropdown gets opened when I click on the selector, it shows the options (`company1` and `company2`), I click on one of them but it does not work -> the value shown is still the placeholder value.

```
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
import { Input, Button, Select, Label, Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const companyOptions = [ // the select's options
  { text: 'company1', value: 'company1' },
  { text: 'company2', value: 'company2' },
];

<Formik
  htmlFor="amazing"
  initialValues={initialValues}
  validationSchema={validationSchema}
  onSubmit={values => this.handleSubmit(values)}>
  {({ errors, touched }) => (
    <Form id="amazing">
      <div>
        <CreationContentContainer>
          <Grid>
            <Grid.Column>
              <Label>Company name</Label>
              <Field
                name="name"
                as={Select} // here is changed to Select
                options={companyOptions} // the options
                placeholder="name"
              />
              <div>{touched.name && errors.name ? errors.name : null}</div>
            </Grid.Column>
          </Grid>
        </CreationContentContainer>
        <Button type="submit" form="amazing">
          Create company
        </Button>
      </div>
    </Form>
  )}
</Formik>;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because Formik passes an `onChange` function into the component. However, the Select (which is just syntactic sugar for dropdown https://react.semantic-ui.com/addons/select/) `onChange` prop uses a function of shape `handleChange = (e: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>, data: SelectProps) => this.setState({value: data.value})` (https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#usage-controlled) which is different than the conventional `handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>) => this.setState({value: event.target.value})` which formik uses.

So an easy solution would be to use the Formik function `setFieldValue`.

In your code, the implementation would be something like this:

```js
const companyOptions = [ // the select's options
  { text: 'company1', value: 'company1' },
  { text: 'company2', value: 'company2' },
];

<Formik
  htmlFor="amazing"
  initialValues={initialValues}
  validationSchema={validationSchema}
  onSubmit={values => this.handleSubmit(values)}>
  {({ errors, touched, setFieldValue, values }) => {
    const handleChange = (e, { name, value }) => setFieldValue(name, value));
    return (
      <Form id="amazing">
        <div>
          <CreationContentContainer>
            <Grid>
              <Grid.Column>
                <Label>Company name</Label>
                <Field
                  name="name"
                  as={Select} // here is changed to Select
                  options={companyOptions} // the options
                  placeholder="name"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={values.name}
                />
                <div>{touched.name && errors.name ? errors.name : null}</div>
              </Grid.Column>
            </Grid>
          </CreationContentContainer>
          <Button type="submit" form="amazing">
            Create company
          </Button>
        </div>
      </Form>
  )}
}
</Formik>;
```

Here's a somewhat working version using your code. The fields update (verified with a console.log), but the submit button isn't working ‍♂️: https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-and-semanticui-select-gb7o7

This is a somewhat incomplete solution and does not handle the onBlur and other injected formik functions. It also defeats the purpose of Formik somewhat. A better solution would be to create a HOC that wraps semantic ui components to use Fromik correctly: https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/148.

And lastly, you can skip the Semantic UI Select and use the Semantic UI HTML controlled `select`: https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#shorthand-field-control-html. Notice the `select` vs `Select`. This will work natively with Formik without the need to pass in `onChange` and `value`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a binding library for [Semantic UI React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/) & [Formik](https://formik.org/).

***Link: https://github.com/JT501/formik-semantic-ui-react***

You just need to import `Select` from the library and fill in `name` & `options` props.

```
// Import components
import { Select, SubmitButton } from "formik-semantic-ui-react";

const companyOptions = [ // the select's options
  { text: 'company1', value: 'company1' },
  { text: 'company2', value: 'company2' },
];

<Formik
  htmlFor="amazing"
  initialValues={initialValues}
  validationSchema={validationSchema}
  onSubmit={values => this.handleSubmit(values)}>
  {({ errors, touched }) => (
    <Form id="amazing">
      <div>
        <CreationContentContainer>
          <Grid>
            <Grid.Column>
              <Label>Company name</Label>

              <Select
                 name="name"
                 selectOnBlur={false}
                 clearable
                 placeholder="name"
                 options={companyOptions}
              />

            </Grid.Column>
          </Grid>
        </CreationContentContainer>
        <SubmitButton>
          Create company
        </SubmitButton>
      </div>
    </Form>
  )}
</Formik>;
```